# What's the so called maliceous-voting-detection worth if this is happening?

Tags: discussion, bug

I just got an interesting message that there had been maliceous voting on my account. Minus almost 6000 reputation.

Interesting question was if I perhaps created an additional account to vote for myself?

Seriously? 
For God's sake I posted [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours)! Please tell me if this is a joke. You cannot take 6000 reputation from someone and expect him or her to stay around. I *never ever* did a single maliceous act here. In short:

I am paying for a crippled detection system

Count me out, I am off.

Comment: A.B. and Fabby lost much more ;-) There are not many people who wrote many good answers. And it is not surprising that they upvoted each other without any cheating.

Comment: So 2 people? hmm

Comment: Not 2. I thing about 10 are affected. I did not dig deep.

Comment: Jacob, this is not that important though. Take it easy, even if it is not fair.

Comment: This doesn't sound like serial voting to me; it sounds like a glitch.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, I appreciate it a lot. I really think however this is fair, and really, it breaks my motivation completely, and not even so much for the points; it demasks the system.

Comment: Every system has glitches from time to time. The motivation is not only points. For me it is not. I post more at forums where there are no points at all.

Comment: The funny thing is reverting accepts from random users.

Comment: @Pilot6 absolutely, but where the *system's* psychology is built on the Pavlov- green candy, a major demotivation on a major push down shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: Is it possible that some user who had passed out a lot of votes deleted his/her account?

Comment: @anonymous2 It is not related to deleted posts at all.

Comment: @anonymous2 no, I got a notification why the minus was. As mentioned, with a nice question if I perhaps used an additional account for upvoting me? The words in my mind that pop up then are no good here. Nor anywhere else.

Comment: @JacobVlijm We all know these people who lost the points today. They are not the same person. And they are not even friendly to each other in some cases ;-)

Comment: You may want to read this http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15520/169736

Comment: my rep is going down as we speak (was -50 now -100)

Comment: @Rinzwind and I'm inoculated :D

Comment: @Rinzwind -160 as we speak...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have a +10 so -170 :)

Comment: @Rinzwind This mornig I was 39600 (about) now less then 34000. No fun any more

Comment: Just guessing from the user's mentioned, but it may be thinking the users who do a lot for the site are rigging the system...

Comment: @JacobVlijm Plese dont quit. We (I) can't afford to lose a great script writer like you. For every problem you came up with amazing scripts!. Well I dont thing there are many more similar guys on AU

Comment: @JacobVlijm If you are interested to know who lost how many (I lost 500+) go to users-->week and browse from the [last page](http://askubuntu.com/users?page=8834&tab=reputation&filter=week)

Comment: @SeverusTux Wow, thanks!