# Why have two of my questions and their answers had a series of unupvotes?

Tags: support, bug, downvoting

Yesterday all my answers to two questions I posted had many votes "unupvoted", including one question.

My [reputation history](https://askubuntu.com/users/146980/devrobot?tab=reputation) and the two questions:

[ASCII screensaver for the command-line or a TUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699579/ascii-screensaver-for-the-command-line-or-a-tui)
[ASCII animations that are viewed in the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699159/ascii-animations-that-are-viewed-in-the-command-line)

What I don't understand is why there are so many unupvotes, on the same sort of questions.

Usually the reason would be due to a user being deleted or a user unupvoting, but after a while you can't reverse your vote...

I'm confused. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to read into a few posts appeared yesterday on Meta where the exact issue has been discussed over and over. Before i put the links just let me cut the story short, there has been some malicious up/down voting on the site and a script introduced yesterday on a first run corrected that and many people have lost  fairly high amounts of reputation.

So here are the links so you can read for yourself.

[Exchange votes or favours](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours)

[I lost 3000+ rep as a reversal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15516/i-lost-3000-rep-as-a-reversal)

[The morning after](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15527/the-morning-after)